# Is there a method for studying music theory through chiptune?

Tags: theory, electronic-music

is there a music course or preferably a book to learn the fundamentals of music but through chiptune and electronic music? something that makes you study, exercise and experiment through these "instruments"?

I admit that the question is a bit particular, so I'll try to add some more detail. It's true it's exactly the music that was made in the old consoles (@Albrecht). If we see it from a musical point of view, it is a very simple genre and on which I think that the theory exercises may not be complicated (and for my ear the sounds remain very distinguishable), if we see it from a more specific point of view, chiptune refers to music reproduced by sound chips such as the commodore, and therefore highly related to its physical limits. I'm intrigued by the idea of learning in this experimental way.

Comment: By "fundamentals" are you excluding how to play music in real time, like through a synthesizer's keyboard?  Will you use only sequencers and software?  Because if you play a keyboard, it hardly matters whether what makes the sounds is hammers hitting strings or wind blowing through organ pipes or current going through a YM2203 chip.  You can use any method at all.

Comment: A quick search on everyone's favourite book shop website reveals titles such as: "Music Theory for Electronic Music Producers", "Simple Music Theory for Electronic Music Production" and "Music Theory for Computer Musicians".

Comment: @YourUncleBob Correct me if I'm wrong, but I was under the impression that chiptune is a very specific subset of electronic music, and I'm not sure how much your recommendations would apply to that specific genre (to be honest, if this question had been asked a year or two ago, I'd have had to google "chiptune").

Comment: Asking for external resources is not wanted here. You should ask for the actual content itself. "How to study music theory using such and such instruments and devices" or something. Though then it might be off-topic for some other reason.

Comment: @ user 45266: I had to google now.  But I just didn't know the term. But we have used this kind of sound 30 years ago on Commodore and Atari .... ;)

Comment: So this must be the sounds I got using Atari and sounds or waves. I don’t whether I’ll find it. But this must have been a quite different language than programs for OS or Windows.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for links like these: http://www.chrisdonnellymusic.com/adventures-in-chiptunes-part-1-an-introduction/ ...https://journal.transformativeworks.org/index.php/twc/article/view/96/94 ...http://micromusic.net/

Answer (score 1):

All theory-links (and most questions and answers of this SE)  are giving information and exercises that you can train on any  instrument, especially on keyboards. Look up fundamental theory.

I'll post you the very first best link I'll find when looking for music fundamentals

http://courses.missouristate.edu/MikeMurray/FundPrimer/PDFs/FundPrimerComplete.pdf

**Update**
This link is no longer valid, but the original can be found here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20201111204310/http://courses.missouristate.edu/MikeMurray/FundPrimer/PDFs/FundPrimerComplete.pdf

Comment: I don’t understand why this answer gets a vote. I’ve looked it up and find it has nothing to do with the question. Nothing at all... I focussed on primer instead of chiptune!